# Is this grammar LL(1)? http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator gives errors

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I have tried using a very simple grammar on the [hackingoff.com](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator) site but I am getting a little confused about the result.

The grammar I used is the following:

```
1. E -> int T
2. T -> + int
3. T -> ε
```

I did some manual calculation and worked out the following:

```
First(int) = {int}
First(+) = {+}
First(ε) = {ε}
First(E) = {int}
First(T) = {+,ε}

Follow(E) ⊆ Follow(T)
First(T) ⊆ Follow(int)
Follow(E) ⊆ Follow(int)
First(int) ⊆ Follow(+)
Follow(E) ⊆ Follow(int)

=>

Follow(E) = {$}
Follow(T) = {$}
Follow(int) = {+,$}
Follow(+) = {int}
```

Then I constructed a parsing table:

```
    int       +       $
  ------------------------
E | int T                |
T |          +int     ε  |
  ------------------------
```

But when I am using this grammar on the [hackingoff.com](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator) site it says - from what I understand - that the grammar has some errors. The table that shows up on the site is the following:

```
[0,"int","+","$"]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,1,5,4]
[0,5,2,3]
```

From what I understand from the description on the site there are errors when - in my case - the value in a cell in the table is greater than 3.
Clearly the problem is in the cells without any production in my table. When I manually constructed the parsing table there where no collisions in the cell so why is it giving me errors? Probably I have missed something fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

Those entries don't indicate errors in your grammar. Rather, they identify syntax errors in the text to be parsed. When the state machine encounters an error value instead of a new state number, it signals a syntax error.

By the way, your grammar only accepts two inputs: `int` and `int + int`. You might want to make T recursive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that my grammar was very fundamental but I just wanted to try the tool with some simple expression.